# Can I use Sparkfun 13.56 to read a cell phone's NFC?

Tags: arduino, nfc, rfid, mifare, hce

I wonder why my Sparkfun 13.56 Eval card (with sm130) is loosing its green 'search' led when reading my cell phones NFC, and won't come back until reset.
The 'found' led lights for a tiny moment when my Mifare cards reads. I thought NFC could be used with it.
I read something about NFC uses a NDEF formatting, but I can't get a grip on it :-)

I have tried Nokia 1520, Sony Experia Z2, Iphone 5, Samsung Galaxy S2 S3 S4 & S5. All with same result.

Can I use it with NFC, and if so: How?

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what you want to achieve. The SM130 is a MIFARE reader that supports only cards/tags with MIFARE Classic and MIFARE Ultralight protocols. Most Android NFC devices cannot emulate such tags.

- Some Android NFC devices have an embedded secure element (or can be used with a UICC-based secure element) that is capable of emulating MIFARE Classic. However it is impossible to modify the data on those secure elements unless you re the logical owner of them (for embedded SE: that's typically the device manufacturer; for UICC: that's typically the mobile network operator).
- Many new Android NFC devices support host-based card emulation (HCE). However, with this card emulation functionality you can only emulate smartcard applications on top of ISO/IEC 7816-4 + ISO/IEC 14443-4, so you cannot emulate a card/tag that can be read with the SM130 (as both MIFARE Classic and MIFARE Ultralight protocols operate on lower protocol layers only).
- With the SM130 "SELECT TAG" and "SEEK FOR TAG" commands you should be able to detect the presence of an Android NFC device (as well as a Nokia Lumia, as well as an iPhone 6). However, for Android devices, you will typically receive a random serial number (that's a requirement for peer-to-peer mode) on every selection -- thus, no usefule information to identify a device. With an iPhone 6 (with activated Apple Pay) you should receive a serial number that can be used to identify the device.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That is to say it is technically capable. It can read the frequency and the format.

There is a lot to it but I'm sure it will be a very rewarding journey.

Github link with an NDEF library:
https://github.com/bjepson/Arduino_NDEF_Reader

On that page you will also find a link for the layout and code on which he based his project. It uses the sm130 so you should be able to use this to get running.

Happy coding!